# Populate Temp Table Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, temp-tables

I have the following three tables in the postgres db of my django app:

```
publication {
    id
    title
}

tag {
    id
    title
}

publication_tags{
    id
    publication_id
    tag_id
}
```

Where tag and publication have a many to many relationship.

I'd like to make a temp table with three columns: 1)publication title, 2)publication id, and 3)tags, where tags is a list (in the form of a string if possible) of all the tags on a given publication.

Thus far I have made the temp table and populated it with the publication id and publication title, but I don't know how to get the tags into it. This is what I have so far:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE pubtags (pub_id INTEGER, pub_title VARCHAR(50), pub_tags VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO pubtags(pub_id, pub_title) SELECT id, title FROM apricot_app_publication
```

Can anyone advise me on how I would go about the last step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [`string_agg`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE):

> `string_agg(expression, delimiter)`
>
> input values concatenated into a string, separated by delimiter

So something like this should do the trick:

```
insert into pubtags (pub_id, pub_title, pub_tags)
select p.id, p.title, string_agg(t.title, ' ,')
from publication p
join publication_tags pt on (p.id = pt.publication_id)
join tag on (pt.tag_id = t.id)
group by p.id, p.title
```

You may want to adjust the delimiter, I guessed that a comma would make sense.

I'd recommend using TEXT instead of VARCHAR for your `pub_tags` so that you don't have to worry about the string aggregation overflowing the `pub_tags` length. Actually, I'd recommend using TEXT instead of VARCHAR period: PostgreSQL will treat them both the same except for wasting time on length checks with VARCHAR so VARCHAR is pointless unless you have a specific need for a limited length.

Also, if you don't specifically need `pub_tags` to be a string, you could use an array instead:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE pubtags (
    pub_id INTEGER,
    pub_title TEXT,
    pub_tags TEXT[]
)
```

and `array_agg` instead of `string_agg`:

```
insert into pubtags (pub_id, pub_title, pub_tags)
select p.id, p.title, array_agg(t.title)
-- as above...
```

Using an array will make it a lot easier to unpack the tags if you need to.

Comment: `I'd recommend using TEXT instead of VARCHAR period`. I can subscribe to that. However, `varchar` *without length specifier* is effectively almost the same as `text`. No length checks.

Comment: @Erwin: True but my experience is that tools, ORMs, and assorted other bits of nastiness are happier to work with `text` than a length-less `varchar` so `text` tends to be easier in real life.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. Follow up question: I decided to follow your array_agg suggestion. So now I'd like to select all the pub_titles for a pub_tag list that contains a particular string as one of its list items - for example, the list item 'tag'. I currently have, (which doesn't work) SELECT pub_title FROM pubtags FIND_IN_SET('%tag%', pub_tags). (This gives a syntax error).  I've been searching for a solution, but this is the closest I've come. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user1697845: `find_in_set` is a MySQLism, no? I think the [contains operator (`@>`)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE) and [ANY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparisons.html#AEN18030) would be useful to you.